# How to override "configure command" parameter in PHP?

Tags: php

I am trying to deploy some PHP scripts on a webserver which is already hosting a live website. In my local development environment the scripts run fine. However, on the server they do not run, and I have traced the problem via the apache error logs to PHP not being able to create a new DOMDocument object. I believe I have narrowed this to a line in the "Configure Command" settings in phpinfo(). In that section, I see `--disable-dom`, as well as `--without-curl`. Both of these should be enabled in order for my script to work properly.

If I can enable these features within my script, that would be great. Otherwise I might need to recompile php, but I'm loathe to do that unless it's absolutely necessary. Is there some way I can override these settings in php.ini, in the script itself at runtime, or through some other method?

Edit: if it helps, the PHP version is 5.3.3-14.el6_3 and it appears that it was installed via `yum`. OS is Scientific Linux 6.3.

Comment: You cannot enable them in the script. You might be able to find a module for your installation. What OS do you use?

Comment: @BartFriederichs Thanks for the suggestion! I already installed php-xml via yum but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Have you tried this PEAR module: https://pear.php.net/package/XML_XPath/ ?

Comment: @BartFriederichs It's obsolete since I'm using 5.3.3. The latest version you can have for XML_XPath is 5.0.0  Thanks though!

Comment: I guess you'll have to rebuild PHP then ... or perhaps you can find a version for your distro that doesn't have `--disable-dom` set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/66189/how-to-enable-dom-without-recompiling-php

Turns out I just needed to restart Apache in this case after running `yum install php-xml`

EDIT: Here's a more thorough overview of what happened here:

PHP 5.3.3 was installed via Scientific Linux's `yum`. by default it installed from the @sl-security repo. This resulted in a compile command that excluded features like curl and DOMDocument.

To enable these features, I ran `yum install php-xml`. I then verified that the appropriate `dom.so` module was loading by inspecting the `dom.ini` file in `/etc/php.d/`.

What I didn't realize was that I needed to restart Apache to make the changes take effect. On this particular system, this was achieved by typing the following:

`service httpd restart`

At this point I was able to use the PHP DOMDocument class.

The "compile command" in phpinfo() just indicates that PHP was compiled without the modules. These modules could be added after the fact using `yum`. I imagine that without yum, one would just need to download the appropriate .so module file and edit php.ini to make sure that module was included.

But of course, the key point is that for any of the changes to take effect, you have to restart Apache. That part was not obvious to me!